# using VNC with SSH securely

Tags: networking, security, vnc, ssl

While I know there is a plethora of available information on how to set up VNC for remote desktop viewing, some of which outlines the importance of using SSH to ensure security, I want to know dome more information.

I had a scare with a brute force attack so I disabled Apache and file sharing over my network to be absolutely sure I wasnt compromised.

I am wondering if using SSH with VNC is a completely secure method of desktop sharing without having my network bombarded with brute force attempts?

Running 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You will have your network bobmarded with login attempts if you have open ports, ssl or now. I advise you use freenx as it is faster and more secure then vnc. You can also configure your firewall. ssl encrypts vnc , but doe not stop login attempts.

Comment: so the answer would be no then ?

Comment: no to what? You are asking many things, apache, ssl, vnc, brute force attacks ... ssl adds security as it encrypts the connection, but ssl does not prevent brute force attempts. You need iptables or fail2ban for that. Your question is too broad.

Comment: Thank you for your response.. I edited post to say 'SSH' not 'SSL'. sorry newbie here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security is complex and you are asking several questions.

First VNC is insecure and one of the most common cracks. This is because, by default, the VNC connection is not encrypted. So there are thus 2 problems-

1. People use insecure passwords (most common problem).
2. The passwords are in plain text and thus can be read by packet
   sniffers (uncommon).

So yes tunneling VNC over ssh will solve the second problem, but, ssh alone will not solve all your problems because:

1. SSH does not enforce strong passwords.
2. SSH introduces a new server that must now be secured.

See also http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/vnc/sshvnc.html or similar

Freenx is faster and more secure than VNC and uses encryption, so solves multiple issues.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX

Now your second question is about "having my network bombarded with brute force attempts"

Your network will be bombarded with brute force attempts if you install a server that enables password authentication such as logging into an Apache web page, ssh, freenx, FTP, etc, etc.

The solution there depends on what you want to do about it and may include things such as:

1. Enforcing strong passwords.
2. A few iptables rules - see http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/iptables#Additional_Tips (scroll down to "Use iptables to reject/block failed connections").
3. Securing your server, varies by server, for ssh see - http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/SSH_security
4. Using a service such as fail2ban.

So, you see, your question is quite broad and there are multiple measures you can take to improve security (this is a short list). See any of the various security guides for more information

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/security.html

And ask a more specific question about a more specific part of security.