# Preventing from DDOS attack

Tags: security

I think I am under a DDOS attack, I found these lines on my access.log:

```
41.214.156.122 - - [21/Mar/2016:06:01:40 +0300] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 41765 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-J700F Build/LMY48B)"
105.154.196.147 - - [21/Mar/2016:06:01:40 +0300] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 41765 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-J700F Build/LMY48B)"
105.154.196.147 - - [21/Mar/2016:06:01:40 +0300] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 41765 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-J700F Build/LMY48B)"
105.154.196.147 - - [21/Mar/2016:06:01:44 +0300] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 41765 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-J700F Build/LMY48B)"
41.143.48.239 - - [21/Mar/2016:06:01:43 +0300] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 41765 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-J700F Build/LMY48B)"
105.154.196.147 - - [21/Mar/2016:06:01:43 +0300] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 41765 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-J700F Build/LMY48B)"
105.154.196.147 - - [21/Mar/2016:06:01:44 +0300] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 41765 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-J700F Build/LMY48B)"
41.214.156.122 - - [21/Mar/2016:06:01:44 +0300] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 41765 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-J700F Build/LMY48B)"
41.143.48.239 - - [21/Mar/2016:06:01:44 +0300] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 41765 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-J700F Build/LMY48B)"
105.154.196.147 - - [21/Mar/2016:06:01:45 +0300] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 41765 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-J700F Build/LMY48B)"
105.154.196.147 - - [21/Mar/2016:06:01:45 +0300] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 41765 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-J700F Build/LMY48B)"
41.143.48.239 - - [21/Mar/2016:06:01:46 +0300] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 41765 "-" "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; SM-J700F Build/LMY48B)"
::1 - - [21/Mar/2016:06:01:52 +0300] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [21/Mar/2016:06:01:53 +0300] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 110 "-" "Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
```

How can I prevent these kinds of attacks?

Thanks

Comment: look at the following url:<br>
[10 Strategies To Fight Anonymous DDoS Attacks](http://www.darkreading.com/vulnerabilities-and-threats/10-strategies-to-fight-anonymous-ddos-attacks/d/d-id/1102699?)<br>
good luck<br>

Answer (score 0):

Depending if you are running a server or not, there are different options to assist you to block IPs. There is a good tutorial on now to block IPs [HERE](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-block-an-ip-on-my-linux-server/).

Also you can:

1. See http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/iptables#Additional_Tips (scroll down to "Use iptables to reject/block failed connections").
2. Securing your server, varies by server, for ssh see - http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/SSH_security
3. Using a service such as [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

There are multiple measures you can take to improve security (this is a short list).See any of the various security guides for more information

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BasicSecurity

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/security.html

In part from **bodhi.zazen**'s answer to my post [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743262/using-vnc-with-ssh-securely).

Comment: Some people said that we need to use the file jail.conf and others said jail.local, which one should I use?